# In passportjs deserialization, store sesssion data in browser cookie

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, passport.js

In passportjs serialization and deserialization, how can I access browser cookie (I am storing session data on persistent browser cookie ) instead of storing in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have configured the passport middleware correctly the passport session data will be passed as parameter to the method passport.deserializeUser.

Be sure that passport has been set up correctly in express:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your secret phrase' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Implement `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser`:

```
// user contains the user data returned by the authentication strategy
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
// obj contains the passport session data
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  // Use obj to get user info or include it directly into the request object  
  done(null, obj);
});
```

User data will be available in `req.user`.

Comment: So it uses the cookie secret to encrypt the user you're serializing?  In the docs, they just serialize the user.id and they say that they do this to save time because it is a smaller object.  Is this cryptographically secure?  Do you know what the behavior of serialize user is if I don't specify a secret?